# How we can create suggest query as per ELasticsearch in opensearch for ContextType of Suggester?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient

I am using Elasticsearch 7.4 and java client api. I want to use context suggester with search api given in this document Suggesters | Elasticsearch Guide [8.6] | Elastic
can any one give me any sample documents which explains how to do in java api service

I am querying like this and my mapping is

```
POST ***_autosuggest/_search?pretty
{
  "suggest": {
    "place_suggestion": {
      "prefix": "tim",
      "completion": {
        "field": "suggest",
        "size": 10,
        "contexts": {
          "genre": [ "**-faculty", "**-companies" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

{
  "**_autosuggest": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "dictionary": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": false,
          "store": true
        },
        "suggest": {
          "type": "completion",
          "analyzer": "suggestionAnalyzer",
          "preserve_separators": true,
          "preserve_position_increments": false,
          "max_input_length": 50,
          "contexts": [
            {
              "name": "genre",
              "type": "CATEGORY"
            }
          ]
        },
        "suggestion": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": false,
          "store": true
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "number_of_shards": "1",
        "provided_name": "***_autosuggest",
        "creation_date": "1679448840300",
        "analysis": {
          "filter": {
            "en_stop": {
              "type": "stop",
              "stopwords": [
                "_english_"
              ]
            }
          },
          "analyzer": {
            "suggestionAnalyzer": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "en_stop"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "0",
        "uuid": "t97z4ZYdRB2KclQV28fTTQ",
        "version": {
          "created": "136277827"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using Elasticsearch 7.4 and java client api. I want to use context suggester with search api given in this document Suggesters | Elasticsearch Guide [8.6] | Elastic
can any one give me any sample documents which explains how to do in java api service

I am trying to create Java API service which will give me results as like following opensearch query.

```
POST ***_autosuggest/_search?pretty
{
  "suggest": {
    "place_suggestion": {
      "prefix": "tim",
      "completion": {
        "field": "suggest",
        "size": 10,
        "contexts": {
          "genre": [ "**-faculty", "**-companies" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand your problem, you talk about opensearch in the title but the question has no relation and you talk about java. Do you want to write suggester in java?

Comment: Yeah, it is quite related to opensearch because I am using its cluster and try to create API service using java which will give me suggest result as like as opensearch.

Comment: I think I answered this question in elastic forum

Comment: I got your response there but I am also trying to get that feature from opensearch also so I posted here I am not getting those implementation in opensearch

Comment: The client lib opensearch is very similar elastic. Those code can works but need some changes.

Comment: those classes are not present in opensearch java clients it seems and there is no example given on suggest query for opensearch side as well.

Comment: Is there anything in elastic side we can ran dsl as it is like String and get response